# How to assign value for element in array at struct pointer in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I have struct like this:

```
struct temper_t {
   unsigned char rom[8];
   struct temper_t *next;
};
```

In this main code, I want assign value for rom[8], how do i can do that:

```
                new_node = (struct temper_t *) malloc(
                        sizeof(struct temper_t));
                new_node->next = NULL;

                int m;
                unsigned char rom_value[8];

                //Luu thong tin vao node moi
                for (m = 0; m < 8; m++) {
                    new_node->rom = rom_value[m]; // not working
                }
```

Thank you for reading my question.

### Update

I create a MCVE for easy understanding:
        /*
         * test.c
         *
         *  Created on: Sep 29, 2015
         *      Author: phuongh1
         */

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdint.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>

    struct temper_t {
        int rom[8];
        struct temper_t *next;
    };

    int main(void) {

        struct temper_t *new_node;
        new_node = NULL;

        int m;
        int rom_value[8];
        rom_value[0] = 10;
        rom_value[1] = 13;
        rom_value[2] = 15;
        rom_value[3] = 16;
        rom_value[4] = 18;
        rom_value[5] = 21;
        rom_value[6] = 25;
        rom_value[7] = 27;

        new_node = (struct temper_t *) malloc(sizeof(struct temper_t));
        new_node->next = NULL;

        //Luu thong tin vao node moi
        for (m = 0; m < 8; m++) {
            new_node->rom[m] = rom_value[m]; // not working
        }

    }
```

### Update: Solved

I found a reason. Because my IDE for firmware coding and it is optimize when compling, the info in debug window shows value of new_node->rom and rom_value not matching. => because firmware code, so I cannot printf value.
After I run code with Visual Studio, they were match.

Comment: no need to cast the return of malloc as it is a void *..  and when writing into the new_node->rom must reference it as `new_node->rom[m] = rom_value[m];` or alternatively use memcpy

Comment: Please do-not change your question significantly after having posted it, as this makes comments/answers already given ununderstandable. I rolled back your last edit therefore. Add addtions as updates.

Comment: @amdixon sorry, i missing this when write this post. In my code, it already has this but the value of rom_value and new_node->rom is not match.

Comment: Please create a MCVE: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @amdixon My code is too long and many Irrelevant code to this question. The code is calculate value to assign **rom_value** variable. After that, I need assign value of **rom_value** to **new_node->rom**

Comment: in order to debug and replicate, a whole program needs to be posted. as others have posted there are tips and techniques for reducing the issue down to a single ( but still runnable ) program

Comment: This updated code appears to work fine.  What happens when you run it?  (Hint: add `printf` statements along the way to ensure values are set correctly.)

Comment: @dbush after run code, the value of new_node->rom not match rom_value.

Comment: Your example does not exhibit the problem (actually it doesn't exhibit anything since it's not printing anything).  Please provide an example that exhibits the problem along with the expected and actual output.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to specify the index of `rom` in the assignment loop:

```
 //Luu thong tin vao node moi
 for (m = 0; m < 8; m++) {
      new_node->rom[m] = rom_value[m]; // not working
 }
```

**Note**: currently you are assigning to `new_node->rom[m]` unknown values since `rom_value` is not initialized.

Comment: sorry, i missing this when write this post. In my code, it already has this but the value of rom_value ang new_node->rom is not match.

Comment: @LangTu according to the currently posted code, this was the only error. Please post all the related code.